# Shader Graph materials are turning to pink in mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I’ve got a problem with my game,

I created a transparent material from a shader graph and that worked in the Windows build but turned pink in the Android build.
[image: 1]

[image]

This is the shader
[image]

I put the shaders into the Always Included shaders list, and move them to the resources folder either.